# Excel Exporting issue using t-sql

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, export

I have windows 10 and office 2007. How to export excel using  t-sql. please provide step by step solution. I am using Openrowset command.

But it gives below error:

**Cannot process the object "SELECT * FROM [ProductList$]". The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.**

Answer (score 0):

I've kinda had such problem, and i've resolved with:

```
T-SQL OPENROWSET from Excel worksheet
-- Import Excel data into global temporary table
DECLARE @SQLconnect VARCHAR(8000), @FileName varchar(256)
SET @FileName='F:\data\export\excel\Top10.xls'
SET @SQLconnect = 'SELECT * INTO ##tmpOrders FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @FileName + ''', ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')'
PRINT @SQLconnect
-- SELECT * INTO ##tmpOrders FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=F:\data\export\excel\Top10.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
EXEC (@SQLconnect)
SELECT * FROM ##tmpOrders
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##tmpOrders
-- 2452
DROP TABLE ##tmpOrders
```

You can adapt the code on your case.